# How to show second alertDialog window depending on the decision in the first alertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have an alertDialog window which shows the simple array list. Each item is the specific command and one of them is "Delete" option. I want the app to show another dialog which asks to confirm the decision made. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    ListView lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter2);

    builder.setView(lv);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditSavedEventActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("EventPosition", pos);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (position == 1) {

                /**************************
                  I want to show the second alertDialog if this option is selected
                 ***************************/

            }
            alert.dismiss();
            onPause();
            onResume();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
```

Comment: just dismiss the current alert and call a function which shows new AlertDialog of delete in the if condition.

Comment: As you can see I have the dismiss() function called outside of all If/else statements at the end. Should I leave it there or copy it inside of the second if statement?

Comment: you can copy it inside. first dismiss and then show your new alert.

Comment: OK. What about the first if statement? There I'm calling new intent. Should I also first dismiss the existing AlertDilog and then start new activity or should I leave dismiss function as it is now? Want to know to have better performance and understanding of best practise

Comment: do you got it fixed

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan for now it seems yes. At least, it works now on my phone. But I would like to know the proper and accurate way of doing it.

Comment: i think method you tried itself seems better..!!